# An audio jack modem

Tags: arduino, audio, adc, fft

I'm looking at controlling Arduino by reading audio commands sent from a raspberry pi (through javascript). I've found the [SoftModem](https://github.com/arms22/SoftModem) code and wonder how it works. It claims that "It uses the phone's audio jack and Bell 202 modem-like FSK encoding", but I wonder how it's done. Doesn't it need to sample the ADC and apply some filtering like FFT? I can't seem to find where all this is done.

Any thought appreciated.

Comment: "SoftModem uses Timer2" Maybe just old-fashioned timing analysis. For details you can look at the Arduino SoftModem.h library.

Answer (score 2):

A radio communication system that had to work in margin signal to noise ratio conditions *would* need to digitise the signal, filter, possibly FFT (usually not), track clock phase, error correct, all that tedious stuff.

However, with a high signal to noise ratio wired connection, this cheap'n'cheerful library uses the analogue comparator to detect when the signal crosses a threshhold, and the timer to measure the length of the high/low periods instead. Sampling happens implicitly in the wait for start bit, wait for data bits, wait for stop bit functions comprising a get data byte state machine for instance. Filtering? *We don't need no steenkin' filtering!*

Read the source code, it's all in SoftModem.cpp that you linked to.

Comment: You don't necessarily need an FFT and a lot of complicated processing.  I've used signaling modules that could pick a PSK signal out of so much noise that you couldn't tell with your ears whether or not there was a signal there to be decoded.  I also got a chance to eyeball the code.  It wasn't much more sophisticated than this "cheap n cheerful" software. It couldn't be, because it ran on a 6502 processor with just a few k of ROM and a few hundred bytes of RAM.

Comment: Just curious, should there be an opamp in that circuit? Shouldn't there be some kind of "signal conditioning" going on there?

Comment: @Kar: The one I mentioned used a kind of schmitt trigger to translate the audio signal to a series of pulses.  There was also a weak band pass filter.